# NavigationUI: How to set action after BottomNavigation item pressed and before navigation destination changed

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I am using BottomNavigation with NavController and I've set it up like this:

```
 NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(fragmentComposeBinding.composeBottomNavView, navController);
```

I want to show a dialog when user presses BottomNavigationItem before loading the destination fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [SweetAlertDialog](https://github.com/F0RIS/sweet-alert-dialog) library to show users a dialog, But it's not important what dialog are you using. you should show dialog instead of navigation action when the user clicks on the item in your BottomNavigation. Then in your dialog, if you have a button, write your navigation action in the onClickListener of dialog's button. else if you're using a delay to dismiss the dialog, right after dismissing command, write your navigation action.